# How to scale up an UIImage without smoothening anything?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimage, core-graphics

I want to scale up an UIImage in such a way, that the user can see the pixels in the UIImage very sharp. When I put that to an UIImageView and scale the transform matrix up, the UIImage appears antialiased and smoothed.

Is there a way to render in a bigger bitmap context by simply repeating every row and every column to get bigger pixels? How could I do that?

Comment: What is your scale factor? Keep in mind that only for x2, x3, x4 etc. you can expect to get "sharp" results.

Comment: Note that this method is known as nearest neighbor interpolation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`#import  <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>`

`view.layer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest`

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if you created the UIImage for the UIImageView with [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ci];

Comment: in addition, use `view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES`. This is to avoid the problem where some images show 4 pixels for every pixel.

Comment: @PeterDeWeese, That's great and achieves my purpose, but I want to ask, when I use `magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest`, are the big and sharp pixels magnified really the original pixels of the image, or just produced by some processing?Thank you!

Comment: @JeffreySun, when I use shouldRasterize = YES, the pixels look like not the original pixels of the image, but the processed ones, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

When drawing directly into bitmap context, we can use:

```
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(myBitmapContext, kCGInterpolationNone);
```

I found this on [CGContextDrawImage very slow on iPhone 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915490/cgcontextdrawimage-very-slow-on-iphone-4/3917789#3917789)

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5**

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Foo")
let scaledImageSize = image.size.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2))

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scaledImageSize)
let scaledContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
scaledContext.interpolationQuality = .none
image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: scaledImageSize))
let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
```

Comment: This solution still adds interpolation to the output. Clearly visible if you attempt to draw sharp color boxes

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying this (on a sublayer) and I couldn't get it working, it was still blurry. This is what I had to do:

```
const CGFloat PIXEL_SCALE = 2;
layer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest; //Nearest neighbor texture filtering
layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(PIXEL_SCALE, PIXEL_SCALE, 1); //Scale layer up
//Rasterize w/ sufficient resolution to show sharp pixels
layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
layer.rasterizationScale = PIXEL_SCALE;
```

Comment: Thanks for the drive-by downvotes... mind explaining what the issue is with this answer?

Answer (score -1):

For UIImage created from CIImage you may use:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(CIImage: ciImage.imageByApplyingTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(kScale, kScale)))
```