# CGContextDrawImage very slow on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, bitmap

I use CGBitmapContextRef for large alterable image.
Than I draw one's parts in UIView.drawRect.
That's work well on iPhone 3GS - 17FPS. 
But on iPhone 4 calling subj method is very slow - and total FPS is 1.5!

profiler says that: on 3GS invokes CGSBlendBGRA8888toRGBA8888 which takes 23% of total time. on 4G same code invokes argb32_sample_RGBA32/argb32_image_mark which takes ~90%. wow!

Color space for bitmap is CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB. And creating flag is kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast.

What can I do for better performance on iPhone 4 ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 8):

Try setting:

```
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(myBitmapContext, kCGInterpolationNone);
```

on your bitmap.  kCGInterpolationLow is another option.

Another technique that may help is add a CALayer to your view, and to set the CALayer's contents to your bitmap, instead of drawing the bitmap image inside the view's drawRect.

Comment: Thanks. I tried yours techniques. 1) kCGInterpolationNone - bad quality for me when scaled. kCGInterpolationLow - good quality and FPS better a few (~5-10%). 2) CALayer.contents don't want to eat CGBitmapContext, just CGImage. But for that case I do next: /* must no ref for context-image when write into */ [.layer.contents = nil]; [change context's pixels]; [.layer.contents = CGBitmapContextCreateImage( pCtx)]; and that code on 3GS gives us 8FPS (was 17) and on 4G 12FPS (was 1.5)

Comment: ... and clear .layer.contents and than setup one blink sometimes

Comment: I rewrote code for using OpenGLES for drawing and using native UI-controls for zoom & scroll. 
I split my Big alterable Image at N*K textures which size is 256x256. sometimes update some of they. 
FPS now: 3G - 27, 3GS - 55, 4G - 60, iPad - 53

Comment: @user396550 I have a very similar problem, and your solution sounds very interesting - are you able to explain in a bit more detail exactly what you did and how, or even share a bit of the code? Perhaps as a new answer to this question. Thanks!